# Please help identify this exotic, probably Japanese board-to-wire connector

Tags: connector, identification

Found on an early 90's JVC stereo: 2 rows, 11 pins, the two rows are horizontally displaced against each other, kind of like a SUB-D connector. However, the pins are neither round, nor quadratic but bars.

The pitch is 3mm (horizontally) by 2mm (between rows)

[image: receptible, soldered onto board]
[image: male connector, crimped onto cable]

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any clue for the brand of the connector? Do you see any logo/letters on it? Are they board-to-board or wire-to-board? Can you please post pictures of the mating mechanism on the sides?

Comment: Also, what is the model of the JVC device? If you are in luck, a service manual for it may be online which can have the part number. See this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/47268182/JVC-TH-M606-603-sm

Comment: It looks kind of like a 11 pin SCART connector (but I'm sure it's not.) The closest I could find is [this](http://caraudiosecurity.com/shop/product/products_id/11348.html).

Comment: Is it a car stereo? http://www.brentwoodcaraudio.com/JVC_11_Pin_Radio_Harness_p/bhjvc11.htm http://www.mobilistics11.mybigcommerce.com/products/JVC-Wiring-Harness-Car-Stereo-11-pin-Wire-Connector.html

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar on OEM GPS modules (inside car radios), medical lab instruments (blood drop analyser) and bank note acceptors (in vending machines).

They were all IDC type onto ribbon cable and most had a projecting plastic key pin on one end. I seem to remember either the plugs or sockets being red in colour often.

The ones I am thinking or are called Micro-MaTch and may be a variant though do not exhibit the zig-zag insulator characteristic.

http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=4-1773457-1&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN